# Does the Microsoft Graph .NET client library support filtering messages by body and creation date?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using this library ([Microsoft Graph .NET client library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)) in my project to retrieve emails from my mailbox. However, when I try to filter messages from my mailbox by createdDateTime or body, I get a "Bad Request" error. Here are my requests:

```
    private static IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage GetMessages(string subject, int count)
    {
        return new graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Filter($"subject eq '{subject}' and createdDateTime gt '{DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)}'").Top(count).GetAsync().Result;
    }

    private static IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage GetMessages(string subject, string bodyPart, int count)
    {
        return new graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Filter($"subject eq '{subject}' and body contains '{bodyPart}'").Top(count).GetAsync().Result;
    }
```

Do the Microsoft Graph API and the library itself that I use support filtering of emails(messages) by createdDateTime and body? And if so, does anyone know what the problem is?

**UPD**

Turns out I had the wrong request to filter the emails by body. Below is the correct query, but I can't find any letters for this query yet. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
    private static IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage GetMessages(string subject, string bodyPart, int count)
    {
        return new graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Filter($"subject eq '{subject}' and contains(body/content, '{bodyPart}')").Top(count).GetAsync().Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering by `createdDateTime` , you should remove `''` and use ISO 8601 format. For example: `2021-07-29T14:32:12Z`

In your case, you can use `ToString("s")`, please find the code as below:

```
return new graphServiceClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Filter($"subject eq '{subject}' and createdDateTime gt {DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10).ToString("s")}Z").Top(count).GetAsync().Result;
```